# How to pass parameter with a href and onclick function?

Tags: javascript, html, variables, href

It is a very simple Javascript functionality but I am not able to get it worked. When I am trying to pass a parameter to an onclick method as follows:

```
<td><b><div id=linkInstall><a href="#" target=_self onClick="show(' + reports + ')" class=right>ABC</a></div></b></td>
```

the show() function treats "report" as a string instead of a variable. Here *reports* is a variable contains some value. Then I tried to escape the string as follows

```
<td><b><div id=linkInstall><a href="#" target=_self onClick="show(\'' + reports + \'')" class=right>ABC</a></div></b></td>
```

then it throws the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

So what is going wrong in this case? How should I pass the variable instead of the string?

Thanks.

Comment: is `report` a JS Variable?

Comment: Basically I am using Django and in the HTML template, there is a python variable named "reports" having some value. Does it answer your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you said that you use Django and HTML, I think the error is with the templating syntax. Try passing the variable inside curly braces.

Example:

```html
<td>
  <b>
    <div id=linkInstall>
      <a href="#" target=_self onClick="show({{ reports }})" class=right>ABC</a>
    </div>
  </b>
</td>
```

Please note that you need to pass the variable to the template as an argument using `TemplateResponse`

```py
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse

def page_name(request, template_name="myapp/inculdes.html"):
    args = {}
    text = {"data":"data"}
    args['reports'] = text
    return TemplateResponse(request, template_name, args)
```